Why don't HTML elements render in Preact?
I'm working on a Preact project, and this is the code of a page:
return (
    <Fragment>
        <div style={gridStyle}>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <Keyboard offset={this.state.octaveAdj} highlightTable={highlightTable} highlightColor={colorIndex} />
        <KeySelector selectedKey={selectedKey} link={true} />
        <Playbox offset={this.state.octaveAdj} highlightTable={highlightTable}
          raiseOctave={this.raiseOctave} lowerOctave={this.lowerOctave}
          risingDisabled={this.state.octaveAdj === MAXoctaveAdj} lowerDisabled={this.state.octaveAdj === MINoctaveAdj}
          color={color} />
        <ChordDetail chord={chord} inversion={inversion} color={color} />
        <ChordSelector selectedKey={selectedKey} />
    </Fragment>
);

Everything renders as intended in the dev server (which is run by Parcel), except the div.
gridStyleis a proper JS object:
const gridStyle = {
  display: 'grid',
  gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(4, 1fr)',
  gridTemplateRows: '1fr 1fr',
};

I tried to take away the div and leave only the p, but nothing changes. That leads me to conclude that this is a problem with every native HTML element, as opposed to components which render fine. But even when I put it in a component, like this:
import { Component } from 'preact'

const styles = {
    display: 'grid',
    gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(4, 1fr)',
    gridTemplateRows: '1fr 1fr', 
};

export default class Test extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={styles}>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>  
        )
    }
}

And add it to the code, it still does not render.
What can be done about this?
Edit: This is my .parcelrc:
{
    "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
    "transformers": {
        "*.{ts,tsx}": [
            "@parcel/transformer-typescript-tsc"
        ]
    },
    "reporters": [
        "...",
        "parcel-reporter-static-files-copy"
    ]
}


I recreated your environment in a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/bhtxvwp3/) but have not been able to reproduce your problem. Can you edit it to reproduce the behavior you're seeing?

How have you configured Parcel? Have you set up JSX correctly?

@JeffBowman How should I reproduce it? I can't just upload the entire project, it's not even my project.

@rschristian I just installed that Babel plugin, and nothing changes. As for Parcel, see my post edit.

@mikwee You need a minimal reproduction, as always. Find the bare minimum repo that demonstrates the issue. We can't help you otherwise, we can't see your files.

@mikwee Everything you showed us looks right, which is why I tried to reproduce it. If you don't know how to make it fail, we certainly won't either. There's a gap somewhere between my working example and your failing case, and without your help I don't know if we have enough information as answerers to close it.

@rschristian @jeff-bowman So listen, I installed two Babel plugins - @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development and @babel/types - and it works now! I had the non-development version of the previous one before, I think I needed the dev version for dev mode!

This was fixed after installing @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development. I was on dev mode while finding the problem, so I think you specifically need the dev version.

If you'd like, you can accept your own answer with the checkmark to indicate that the question is solved. Glad you got your environment working!
